# Ansible, vmware_guest, customvalues syntax

Tags: vmware-esxi, ansible

I've tried this every way I can think of and it refuses to set the "customvalues" on the VM.

```
- name: Cloning VM
  vmware_guest:
   validate_certs: no
   hostname: "{{ vcenterhostname }}"
   username: "{{ vcusername }}"
   ...

   template: "{{ item.key }}"
   name: new_vm0001
   customvalues:
    - remotedisplay.vnc.port: 6021
  state: restarted
  when:
    - item.key | search('-sourcevm')
with_dict: "{{ vmfacts.virtual_machines }}"
delegate_to: localhost
```

Has anyone been able to successfully set customvalues?

Using ansible 2.4, I suppose it could be broken but more likely I don't have the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use your favourite search engine to locate [`vmware_guest` module manual](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vmware_guest_module.html)
2. Read:

   > `customvalues`
   >
   > Define a list of customvalues to set on VM.
   >
   > A customvalue object takes 2 fields `key` and `value`.
3. Implement:

   ```
   customvalues:
     - key: remotedisplay.vnc.port
       value: 6021
   ```

Comment: Verbose output --

    "customvalues": [
                {
                    "key": "remotedisplay.vnc.port", 
                    "value": "6201"
                }
            ], 

Error msg

    "msg": "Failed to set custom value for key='remotedisplay.vnc.port' and value='6201'. Error was: (vmodl.fault.InvalidArgument) {\n   dynamicType = <unset>,\n   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],\n   msg = 'A specified parameter was not correct: key',\n   faultCause = <unset>,\n   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [],\n   invalidProperty = u'key'\n}"